# How to do the optimization by using udf in select query

Tags: sql-server-2008

we are running a job every day. It is taking around 2 hours to run. we are trying to optimization the performance.

In view we wrote the  5 UDF funcitons which I used to lookup data and return values based on the condition in select query.

`select [ECX_Version_UID],[Object Type],[AMT_ECXHeader],[Description],LMUser,[Created Date],

```
--UDF Functions 
ISNULL(eng_kpi.udf_ProjectX_Get_LastModifiedDate(EC_Number),'') as LastModifiedDate,
ISNULL(eng_kpi.udf_ProjectX_Get_CEImpact(EC_Number),'') as [Change category]
ISNULL(eng_kpi.udf_ProjectX_Get_SPS_References (EC_Number),'') as [SPS References],
ISNULL(eng_kpi.udf_ProjectX_Get_ESW_References(EC_Number),'') as [ESW References],
ISNULL(eng_kpi.udf_ProjectX_Get_Prerequisite_ECRs(EC_Number),'') as [Prerequisite ECRs]


From #Loctable`
```

If i run view the with out udf function it is taking 20 seconds to run.
Is it any impact to write the UDF in select Query.

Comment: " Is it any impact to write the UDF in select Query" - yes. Don't use scalar valued UDFs, use inline TVFs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Scalar Valued function impacts the performance of the query negatively. From SQL 2005 onwards, SQL Server introduced new features like APPLY (CROSS or OUTER) statements and CTE (in case you have to use loops), by using those you can easily replace your UDFs. This will definitely improve your query's performance.